# Why does my htaccess file does not redirect links without http

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect

I have been trying to make redirects through my website,  but currently when i give the redirect link it does not correctly redirect unless you add the **`http`**

The redirect url

```
tracker02.globaltracking.com/ric?track=100&go=www.fox.com
```

.htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{ENV:PROCESSED} TRUE
RewriteRule (.*) $1 [S=2]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^.*([^?&]*)go=
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^.*([^?&]*)track=
RewriteRule ^(rd) /redirect.php

RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} id=([^;]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(rd)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/pros_redirect.php?atid=%1 [R=permanent,QSA,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !id=[^;]+ [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^.*&go=([^?&]*)\??([^&]*)&*.*$
RewriteRule ^ric$ ${allowed_sites:%1|/ric.gif}?%2 [NE,E=PROCESSED:TRUE]

RewriteCond %{ENV:PROCESSED} TRUE
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)%26(.*)$
RewriteRule (.*) $1?%1&%2 [NE,N]

RewriteCond %{ENV:PROCESSED} TRUE
RewriteRule (.*) $1 [NE,L]

RewriteRule ^(ric)$ /ric.gif [L]
```

can anybody help me on this.. the error i get is

> The requested URL /www.fox.com was not found on this server.

Comment: any htaccess experts out there

Comment: Difficult to understand your rules and problem you're facing. What URL do you enter in the browser that is causing 404? Just fyi `QUERY_STRING` never has `?` character in it so I'm not sure how is `RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^.*&go=([^?&]*)\??([^&]*)&*.*$` working for you.